# Efficiently and Quickly cast a java.sql.ResultSet to String Array or ArrayList?

Tags: java, sql, resultset

I have a java.sql.ResultSet and calling next() to iterate over the elements (the columns) is the major performance hit in my code, and I know having a contiguous array would be faster because of memory/cache reasons (the ArrayList would be contiguous since I only allocate it once and don't call add() on it).

I have seen various ways of casting it, but none have worked. I would not want to use a for loop to iterate over the elements, since that would be calling next(), what I'm trying to avoid. My ResultSet has many elements in it, so is there a way to cast the RS to an array or ArrayList?

Comment: No. A `ResultSet` object has absolutely nothing to do with an array or `List`. It is also unlikely there is any "performance issue" involved with iterating through it.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no other way.  the problem isn't your use of the `.next()` call, the problem is a slow database.  there might be some optimizations you need to perform on your database and/or your jdbc connection, however you would need to provide a lot more details about your actual use case.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to retrieve rows from a `ResultSet` other than by calling `next()`.

The underlying implementation may not materialize a given row until you ask for it, and that may involve network traffic.  A reasonable implementation will fetch rows in batches and cache them until you ask for them, but it certainly will not fetch ALL the rows at once unless the resultset is small.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. What would be a good way to fetch all the rows? The code uses a Connection object with executeQuery(query).

Comment: I'm not sure what was unclear about my answer.  You have to loop over the rows one at a time. If you want to you can use `setFetchSize(n)` on the `ResultSet` or `Statement` object to ask the JDBC driver to batch its back-end retrievals.  But _you_ still have to retrieve rows one by one.